# PHP file output, random spaces in feed

Tags: php

The following function is supposed to read a file, increment and then output to a file the following to a text document:

```
function updateDaysAway($tenantName, $datefrom, $dateto){
    $names = array();
    $days = array();
    $file = fopen("data/daysaway.txt", 'a+');

    while (!feof($file)) {
        $data = fgets($file);
        if(!$data == '') {
            $pieces = explode(" ", $data);
            $names[] = $pieces[0];
            $days[] = $pieces[1];
        }
    }

    fclose($file);

    for($x = 0; $x < count($names); $x++) {
        if(strtolower($names[$x]) == strtolower($tenantName)){
            $datefromVAR = new DateTime($datefrom);
            $datetoVAR = new DateTime($dateto);
            $file = fopen("data/range.txt", 'a+');
            $days[$x] +=  $datetoVAR->diff($datefromVAR)->format('%a')+1;
        }
    }

    $file = fopen("data/daysaway.txt", 'w');

    for($x = 0; $x < count($names); $x++) {
        $entry = $names[$x]." ".$days[$x].PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($file, $entry);
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Original file

```
"
name 185
name 0
"
```

After file

```
"
name 185
name 0




 // Random white space I don't want



"
```

Instead it outputs incrementally(Seems to increase after each write), an empty space and " " randomly at the end of the line and randomly in-between. Do you have any information on how to solve?

Comment: I guess that `if(!$data == '')` should be `if($data != '')`?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Nope, both methods work exactly the same.

Comment: Actually, they don't: https://3v4l.org/TFEsG. PHP's type juggling has a bunch gotchas. Anyway, it just feels weird to use an array as a boolean just to compare it to a string.

Comment: Have you tried debugging by writing an extra line like "-----" after every fwrite? Also try outputting the size of the names and days arrays - there might be something funny in the read method

Comment: I suspect that somehow your `$names` array is larger than the actual entries. Try outputting the `count()` or `sizeof()` of it. If not, maybe temporarily add `ini_set('display_errors', true);` to the top of your file and see if it shows something helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue

the

```
    $pieces = explode(" ", $data);
    $names[] = $pieces[0];
    $days[] = $pieces[1];
```

when reading the file into array, the days parameter(side of the explosion) was including the invisible newline. God I hate PHP!!